# can I have more than two finally block in a class

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I am working on a project where I need to perform two different operation.
I have a finally block in my main controller method.

My question is, can I have more than two finally, for example:

```
class test
{
    X()
    {
        try
        {
            //some operations
        }
        finally
        {
            // some essential operation
        }

    }

    //another method
    Y()
    {
        try
        {
            //some operations
        }
        finally
        {
            // some another essential operation
        }
    }
}
```

so,is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?  If so, what exactly didn't work?

Comment: every try-catch block may have a finally, so what you've shown here is possible

Comment: Would have been simpler for you to have typed this into Eclipse rather than stackOverflow and you'd have got the answer in the process.

Comment: Title: *"clacan I have more than thwo finally block in a class"* Content: Poorly-formatted code block. Perhaps just a **bit** more effort?

Comment: You can have one finalyy block for one try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I have more than two finally

Yes, you can have as many `try - catch - finally` combination you want but they all should be correctly formatted. (i.e syntax should be correct)

In your example, you've written correct syntax and it'll work as expected.

You can have in following way:

```
try
{

}
catch() // could be more than one
{

}
finally
{

}
```

OR

```
try
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch() // more than one catch blocks allowed
    {

    }
    finally // allowed here too.
    {

    }
}
catch()
{

}
finally
{

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can only have one `finally` clause *per try/catch/finally statement*, but you can have multiple such statements, either in the same method or in multiple methods.

Basically, a try/catch/finally statement is:

- `try`
- `catch` (0 or more)
- `finally` (0 or 1)

... but there must be *at least* one of `catch`/`finally` (you can't have just a "bare" `try` statement)

Additionally, you can nest them;

```
// Acquire resource 1
try {
  // Stuff using resource 1
  // Acquire resource 2
  try {
    // Stuff using resources 1 and 2
  } finally {
    // Release resource 2
  }
} finally {
  // Release resource 1
}
```

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: Yes. Your question was unclear on this - in particular, your examples didn't attempt to use more than one `finally` block per `try` block.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{

        try{
            int[] a =new int[5]; 
            a[5]=4;
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                            {
               System.out.println("Out Of Range");
            }finally{
                System.out.println("Finally Outof Range Block");
                }

        try{            
            int x=20/0;
            }catch (ArithmeticException e)
                              { 
                                  System.out.println("/by Zero");                                                                            

            }finally{
                System.out.println("FINALLY IN DIVIDES BY ZERO");
                }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("FINALLY IN EXCEPTION BLOCK");
    }
    System.out.println("COMPLETED");

     }
}
```

......

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer, especially *Provide context for links* part.